# adding x and y axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, label, ggplot2

How do I change the x and y labels on this graph please?

```
library(Sleuth2)
library(ggplot2)
discharge<-ex1221new$Discharge
area<-ex1221new$Area
nitrogen<-ex1221new$NO3
p <- ggplot(ex1221new, aes(discharge, area), main="Point")
p + geom_point(aes(size= nitrogen)) + 
    scale_area() + 
    opts(title = expression("Weighted Scatterplot of Watershed Area vs. Discharge and Nitrogen Levels (PPM)"), 
         subtitle="n=41")
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

[Note: edited to modernize ggplot syntax]

Your example is not reproducible since there is no `ex1221new` (there is an `ex1221` in `Sleuth2`, so I guess that is what you meant). Also, you don't need (and shouldn't) pull columns out to send to `ggplot`. One advantage is that `ggplot` works with `data.frame`s directly.

You can set the labels with `xlab()` and `ylab()`, or make it part of the `scale_*.*` call.

```
library("Sleuth2")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(ex1221, aes(Discharge, Area)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=NO3)) + 
  scale_size_area() + 
  xlab("My x label") +
  ylab("My y label") +
  ggtitle("Weighted Scatterplot of Watershed Area vs. Discharge and Nitrogen Levels (PPM)")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(ex1221, aes(Discharge, Area)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=NO3)) + 
  scale_size_area("Nitrogen") + 
  scale_x_continuous("My x label") +
  scale_y_continuous("My y label") +
  ggtitle("Weighted Scatterplot of Watershed Area vs. Discharge and Nitrogen Levels (PPM)")
```

[image]

An alternate way to specify just labels (handy if you are not changing any other aspects of the scales) is using the `labs` function

```
ggplot(ex1221, aes(Discharge, Area)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=NO3)) + 
  scale_size_area() + 
  labs(size= "Nitrogen",
       x = "My x label",
       y = "My y label",
       title = "Weighted Scatterplot of Watershed Area vs. Discharge and Nitrogen Levels (PPM)")
```

which gives an identical figure to the one above.

Answer (score 2):

since the data ex1221new was not given, so I have created a dummy data and added it to a data frame. Also, the question which was asked has few changes in codes  like then ggplot package has deprecated the use of

```
"scale_area()" and nows uses scale_size_area()
"opts()" has changed to theme()
```

In my answer,I have stored the plot in mygraph variable and then I have used

```
mygraph$labels$x="Discharge of materials" #changes x axis title
       mygraph$labels$y="Area Affected" # changes y axis title
```

And the work is done. Below is the complete answer.

```
install.packages("Sleuth2")
library(Sleuth2)
library(ggplot2)

ex1221new<-data.frame(Discharge<-c(100:109),Area<-c(120:129),NO3<-seq(2,5,length.out = 10))
discharge<-ex1221new$Discharge
area<-ex1221new$Area
nitrogen<-ex1221new$NO3
p <- ggplot(ex1221new, aes(discharge, area), main="Point")
mygraph<-p + geom_point(aes(size= nitrogen)) + 
  scale_size_area() + ggtitle("Weighted Scatterplot of Watershed Area vs. Discharge and Nitrogen Levels (PPM)")+
theme(
 plot.title =  element_text(color="Blue", size=30, hjust = 0.5), 

 # change the styling of both the axis simultaneously from this-
 axis.title = element_text(color = "Green", size = 20, family="Courier",)
 

   # you can change the  axis title from the code below
   mygraph$labels$x="Discharge of materials" #changes x axis title
   mygraph$labels$y="Area Affected" # changes y axis title
   mygraph
```

Also, you can change the labels title from the same formula used above -

```
mygraph$labels$size= "N2" #size contains the nitrogen level
```