# How to display 0 value in a bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have this data frame called data:

> head(data)

```
     date         total_sold purchasability visibility
81 2014-05-01          3              3          3
82 2014-05-02          2              2          3
83 2014-05-03          1              2          3
84 2014-05-04          1              3          3
85 2014-05-05          3              2          3
86 2014-05-06          0              0          3
```

And I would like to do a bar chart with x = date and y = total_sold with a color depending on the purchasability. I this ggplot2 to do that :

```
bar <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, fill=as.factor(purchasability),y = total_sold)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

The output is very nice but the problem is that where total_sold = 0 there is not chart and thus no way to know the purchasability. Is it possible to still display a bar (maybe from 0.5 to -0.5) when total_sold = 0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a simple way to go from 0.5 to -0.5 but you can easily show the 0 value as being a fraction (eg -0.1) by modifying the value in your `bar=` line to:

```
bar <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, fill=as.factor(purchasability),y = sapply(total_sold, FUN=function(x) ifelse(x==0, -0.1,x) ))) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

This produces:
[image]

It is a little misleading to show 0 as something other than 0, but I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does the job, but I tried to change the y lab with ylab="Sales Volume" but it keeps me the sapply. Can you please know how to edit that ? And also how to change the naming in the legend (as.factor(purchasability))

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438752/adding-x-and-y-axis-labels-in-ggplot2 - the syntax is ...+ylab("Sales Volume")... for the y-axis label. For the legend, see http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/ - use  ...+guides(fill=guide_legend(title="MY_TITLE"))...

Answer (score 12):

You can just use geom bar, please look this code

```
df <- data.frame(time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","breakfast","test"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner","breakfast","test")),
                  total_bill = c(14.89, 0,0.5,-0.5))
# Add a black outline
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) + geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity")
```

[image]